# js_callfunctionname crashed in cocos2d js

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

I am new to cocos2d js, I develop a game in cocos2d js. It is suddenly crashed with in 10mints. 
Please check screenshot below.
[image]

I don't have any idea about this crash. 
Please help me.
(this is memory issue)
Please help me.
Thank you...

Comment: Did you notice you have sprite batch node with 552+ children?

Comment: one sprite batch node have around 300 children, can you explain